# Make MFC Modal (synchronous)

Tags: c++, mfc, modal-dialog, synchronous

I have crated an MFC GUI application (blah.exe), and it works fine.  I need to use it in a powershell script, and I need the script to wait for the .exe application to finish.  But the .exe runs itself asynchronously, i.e. the invoking process does not wait for it to finish.  How do I change this?

The application was created in Visual Studio 2010 with the standard MFC app wizard.

Comment: Does the app exit when you start it from PowerShell but works normally if you start it manually? Is that what you saying?

Comment: It exits immediately regardless of how it is started. This is by design of MFC gui applications I believe. I want to change that for my application. I suspect the answer will be to create a console app that creates all the dialogs, but want to know if there is a simpler method.

Comment: The problem is *not* that the exe exits, it will continue to run until the dialog goes away. The problem is making powershell wait for it. You can see this for yourself with Task Manager.

Comment: Correct, I was sloppy in my use of terminology.  The exe process of course continues to run.  But it runs asynchronously - it has nothing to do with powershell.  Same behaviour no matter how it is invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start your application using the following command in PowerShell:

```
Start-Process <path to exe> -NoNewWindow -Wait
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks.  Much easier than changing the .exe

Comment: @DavidI.McIntosh there's no change you could make to the .exe that would result in the behavior you need. This is the answer.

Comment: @MarkRansom Could you expand on your comment or provide a link?  I'd like to understand.  Thanks.